# Penalty for impersonating a Brahmin

Tags: caste-system, marriage

My family has observed the rules of marriage according to the scriptures.

However, in the case of my cousin sister, her husband is a Sudra who impersonated a Brahmin in order to marry her.

He is an actor by profession, and is very good at memorizing things.  After marriage, he told that he got coaching from his Brahmin neighbor.

Now, my uncle's family has gone into depression.

People will talk behind their backs and make fun of them in family functions.

This is not a case of person born into Sudra caste but has Brahmin qualities.

This is a case of a person who manipulated the system to get worldly gain.

Is there any mention of such a scenario in the scriptures, and what is the penalty?

Comment: Yours is a duplicate of [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26941/is-hiding-ones-caste-a-punishable-offense). see the answer there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is hiding one's caste a punishable offense?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26941/is-hiding-ones-caste-a-punishable-offense)