# Searching for source for a quote I came across on Hinduism stackexchange

Tags: mahabharata, karna, parashurama

I came across the following quote in this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37413/32655

> Any knowledge gained by lie or deciet is fruitless and will definitely fail to deliver when one need it the most, this is not my curse but law of nature

The author of that answer describes that the words above were bhagwan Parashuram ji's response to Karna when Karna inquired about the curse.

I've come across something similar in other places too.
I am just curious if there are any religious scriptures which happen to mention this.

*I would have requested for the source in a comment on that answer, however my reputation points don't allow me to post comments yet.*

Comment: This translation isn't the best, but you are referring to the curse of Parashurama from the Adiparva.